# Magento Block overriding error

Tags: magento

I am trying to override the 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid' block. My code in config.xml is as in below:

```
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite><report_sales_sales>Tal_SalesOrderReports_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid</report_sales_sales></rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

Then i am getting below error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function hasData() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Grid\Abstract.php on line 102

Can anyone please help me. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your XML, you're trying to override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Sales, not Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Sales_**Grid**. If you want to override the grid, then your XML should look like this:

```
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite><report_sales_sales_grid>Tal_SalesOrderReports_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid</report_sales_sales_grid></rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
```

Comment: Yes I made that mistake. Also in block class, it should be like below: class Tal_SalesOrderReports_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Sales_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Abstract   Thank You Alexei